# su: /bin/bash: No such file or directory in Dragonfly BSD

Tags: shell, login, dragonflybsd

today I wanted to change my shell to BASH from sh.
I have only the root account on my system.

I typed `chsh -s /bin/bash` but the BASH shell is in the `/usr/local/bin/bash`. So after a logout I am unable to login to my system. I have no way to chroot (because it's a virtual machine).

Is there any alternative way to get back into the system?

Comment: Reboot into single user mode and change the shell there?  Why are you changing root's shell anyway? You should be using a non-privileged user account.

Comment: I can't change the shell from single user mode. When I try to use the chsh command, it says `chsh: pw_tmp(): Read-only file system`

Comment: Then remount the root partition as `rw`. `mount -u -o rw /` or something similar.

Comment: Yes, that worked... It's so different from GNU/Linux, so I tried creating a symbolic link to /bin/bash... Thanks a lot!

Comment: I wouldn't create that symbolic link. Just reset the root user's shell to whatever it was from the start and create another user. If you want `bash` for that user, use `/usr/local/bin/bash`.

Comment: **If** you have another account that can `su` to root you can run `su -s /usr/local/bin/bash` and then run `chsh` again.  Or if that user can run `chsh` from sudo: `sudo chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash root`.